# Safe way to backup whatsapp messages?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

I recently had to reset my phone. I had the nightly msgstore.db.crypt7 file, which I fortunately decrypted (and can view in sqlite browser), but whatsapp refuses to restore from it. Maybe it is because the file is too big (10.2MB), or maybe there's a small corruption somewhere, I don't know.

When looking for backup apps, all I found were those that will take the msgstore.db and upload it. SMS backup+ will break it to individual messages, but then can't restore.

So is there a method/app that can upload the conversation in some corruption-safe way (so that if a small portion gets corrupted, the rest is still usable)? So that it is done automatically (nightly)?

Comment: Any sort of backup file will need metadata and/or a strict format to be useful, it can't just be the straight text of every message -- you want to know who sent it, when, etc.  Most corruptions will result in an unusable file; your only option would be to repair it.  There's no special way to avoid this.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Whats App FAQ section](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23756533):

> Your WhatsApp messages are automatically backed up and saved on your
>   phone's memory daily. If you delete WhatsApp from your phone and don't
>   want to lose any of your messages, be sure to **manually back up your
>   chats before uninstalling**:
>
> 1. Go to WhatsApp > Menu Button > Settings > Chat Settings.
> 2. Tap Backup Conversations.
>
> To export a copy of the history of an individual chat
>   or group, you can use the Email Chat History feature:
>
> 1. Tap and hold on the conversation or group.
> 2. Select Email conversation.
> 3. Choose whether to Attach Media or not.
>
> An email will be composed with your chat history attached as a .txt document.
>
> If you choose to attach media, the most recent media sent will be
>   added as attachments.

This should be enough to solve your problem.

Comment: "Backup Conversations" will just export an sqlite file. Any corruption makes the file unusable. It is also not automatic. Emailing individual chats is even less automatic and cannot be used to restore.